# Joining two tables with foreign key - SQL

Tags: sql, database

I' am trying to join data prom two tables having only foreign key in common. 
I want to display part_number and summary quantity for sales and claims.

I have been trying with different query but if it returns values, the values are not correct.

```
select id.part_number, sum(id.quantity) as sales, sum(c.quantity) as claims
from claims as c, invoice_details as id
where c.part_number = id.part_number
group by id.part_number
order by claims DESC
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to aggregate *before* `JOIN`ing:

```
select id.part_number, id.sales, c.claims
from (select c.part_number, sum(c.quantity) as claims
      from claims c
      group by c.part_number
     ) c join
     (select id.part_number, sum(id.quantity) as sales
      from invoice_details id
      group by id.part_number
     ) id
     on c.part_number = id.part_number
group by id.part_number
order by claims desc;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Correct. The deeper reason for the original query's wrong results is that if you have _N_ claims and _M_ invoice records for a given query, the original query will return _N * M_ rows to group over, so each `quantity` value is counted multiple times.